# wrong generation of R.java drawables

Tags: java, android, xml, resources, r.java-file

Heyho,

I have a problem concerning the R.java file. Actually I caused it myself by creating a drawable icon called 'ic_tab_debate.png' in all drawable folders (mdpi, hdpi, ...) but also creating and XML file in the drawable folder called 'ic_tab_debate.xml'. This of course led to the problem. But after deleting the XML file there still is something wrong in the R.java!

My drawable part of the R.java file looks like this:

```
public static final class drawable {
    public static final int =0x7f020022; //Here is the problem
    public static final int common_signin_btn_icon_dark=0x7f020000;
    public static final int common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_dark=0x7f020001;
    public static final int common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_focus_dark=0x7f020002;
    public static final int common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_focus_light=0x7f020003;
    public static final int common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_light=0x7f020004;
    public static final int common_signin_btn_icon_focus_dark=0x7f020005;
    public static final int common_signin_btn_icon_focus_light=0x7f020006;
    public static final int common_signin_btn_icon_light=0x7f020007;
    public static final int common_signin_btn_icon_normal_dark=0x7f020008;
    public static final int common_signin_btn_icon_normal_light=0x7f020009;
    public static final int common_signin_btn_icon_pressed_dark=0x7f02000a;
    public static final int common_signin_btn_icon_pressed_light=0x7f02000b;
    public static final int common_signin_btn_text_dark=0x7f02000c;
    public static final int common_signin_btn_text_disabled_dark=0x7f02000d;
    public static final int common_signin_btn_text_disabled_focus_dark=0x7f02000e;
    public static final int common_signin_btn_text_disabled_focus_light=0x7f02000f;
    public static final int common_signin_btn_text_disabled_light=0x7f020010;
    public static final int common_signin_btn_text_focus_dark=0x7f020011;
    public static final int common_signin_btn_text_focus_light=0x7f020012;
    public static final int common_signin_btn_text_light=0x7f020013;
    public static final int common_signin_btn_text_normal_dark=0x7f020014;
    public static final int common_signin_btn_text_normal_light=0x7f020015;
    public static final int common_signin_btn_text_pressed_dark=0x7f020016;
    public static final int common_signin_btn_text_pressed_light=0x7f020017;
    public static final int ic_launcher=0x7f020018;
    public static final int ic_launcher_sw=0x7f020019;.......
```

However, deleting the R.java file and cleaning the project didn't solve my problem. The wrong R.java is always regenerated. There is a resource without a name, but I don't know how to delete this =0x7f020022 out of it.

Thanks for you help in advance :)

Comment: Delete `bin` folder and then clean the project.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried it, but it didn't work as well. When I delete the bin folder outside of eclipse than it rebuilts again. and when I want to delete it in eclipse I get an error messae saying: "Resource '<projectname>/bin' is out of sync with file system." What does that mean?

Comment: Try to Right-click your project > Refresh, Right-click again > Code > Clean Up.

Comment: Ok, deleting bin folder worked after refreshing and cleaning up, but problem still appeares :(

Comment: Project/Clean - And if it doesn't solve, restart Eclipse

Comment: Restarting Eclipse did not help as well. Another the precise information about my error is: Syntax error on token "int", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token

Answer (score 0):

delet R.java and restart eclipse
make sure drawables files is not with capital letters

Comment: I did that, but after restarting eclipse and cleaning project the wrong R.java file was there again.

Comment: try change any thing  in R.java file it will generate new code 
and see if public static final int =0x7f020022; //Here is the problem still the same

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your support! I finally found the solution to my question! Afterwards I can say, it's just a small and silly error, but I was going crazy when I asked it.
And actually it is a mistake that could only happen to germans. I thought the problem was due to the files with the same name. But previously I added another file named 'ic_tab_hlü.png'. The german mutated vowel ü is not allowed for resources. That's why the R.java file was not generating correctly!
And thus deleting the bin folder or R.java file didn't change anything because the problem's roots were not cut and the files were regenerated incorrectly.

However, thanks a lot for helping me. I'll try to use English file names only in the future :)